# Screen tearing while browsing the internet (chrome+firefox) in ubuntu 12.04 intel 4000 graphics

Tags: 12.04, intel-graphics, tearing

First, some specs: Ubuntu 12.04 on an Asus UX31A Zenbook Prime, running kernel 3.5.0-10. As stated in the title, Intel 4000 graphics.

While browsing the internet in both chrome and firefox, I get REALLY bad screen tearing. It seems to happen the worst on gmail, and when opening drop-down menu's. Also happens on youtube when you drop down the little description thing. It causes screen tearing and a lot of blank spaces that *sometimes* will reappear if you move the mouse over them. The strangest thing about it is that I don't get any tearing at all while streaming videos. Only while doing general browsing. Now that I am actually typing it out it sounds like it could be a javascript problem. Who knows? Hopefully one of you do.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using 12.04 with Intel HD 4000 graphics and a stock kernel (3.2.0-29-generic) and have not noticed these problems.  I also have another partition that is Xubuntu 12.04 and has a custom compiled 3.4.x family kernel, which also does not see this problem.

The 3.5.x and 3.6.x kernels are known to be introducing a number of more experimental and untested capabilities for the new Intel HD 4000 chipsets.  As such it would not surprise me if your problem is related to a bug in one of these introductions.

I would suggest testing out a more stable kernel (3.2.x or 3.4.x family) and see if the problem disappears. If it does you can [file a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs/) against the 3.5.0-10 kernel on launchpad (and potentially upstream as well).

Comment: I just went ahead and completely reinstalled. The problem is gone now, I guess it was just the kernel *sadface*.

Comment: Glad to hear your problem is gone.  If it was the kernel, you could have just uninstalled the 3.5.x kernel (or just chosen an older kernel from the Grub menu) rather than completely re-installing.